# Add RSS feeds to google reader from iPad

Tags: rss, ipad, google

When using iPad, with Safari or some other application, once I find an interesting blog with its RSS feed, how can I add it to my google reader feeds?

Answer (score 1):

If you use an RSS reader like [Mr Reader](http://www.curioustimes.de/mrreader/) or [Reeder](http://reederapp.com/ipad/), you can add new subscriptions using the + button on the main screen of each.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest route is to add a bookmarklet. See [this link](http://www.todaysiphone.com/2010/07/tips-tricks-add-bookmarklets-to-mobile-safari/) for details as well as the necessary Javascript you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Opera Mini on your iPad, it is easy to add url in there :)

Answer (score -1):

Google reader is being decommissioned at the end of June. Ironically, a google search can point you to many other RSS sync services to replace google reader with.